# DELL XPS 13 Sound Problem

Tags: dell, alsa, xps, noise, hda-intel

Since the last update (20.11.2013) for Ubuntu 13.10 there are noises in the left speaker. They appear in the internal speakers when I boot the system and if I choose the audio jack in the external speakers.
Do anyone else have those same problems? What could it be?

I have allready add this ppa
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu saucy main

from
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily

Comment: -1 since the issue ended up being a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now the problem is gone. The DELL service have sent an Technician and have changed my sound card and motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

http://mangel312.blogspot.nl/2014/06/installing-ubuntuxubuntu-on-dell-xps.html

it helps for my xps 13 , 
i had noise in my headphones

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, add essential part of the link to your answer.